# Condition bits in SWI (ARM Instruction)

Tags: assembly, arm

In ARM SWI instruction 32 bits are divided into 3 sets: 0:23 (System Call Number), 24:27 (0b1111), and 28:31 (Condition). **What is the condition?**

The book 'ARM SoC Architecture' mentions that '**If condition is passed the instruction enters supervisor mode.**' When i check the sample code then the example has one CMP condition before the SWI but I am still not able to understand the reason for the condition. Moreover, several presentations on 'SWI for ARM' present on the Internet don't have any CMP condition before SWI. So I am confused that whether we need it or not and if yes, then what is the need?

Please help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: every arm instruction has a condition.  most of the time it is 0b1110 (0xE) which means always.  As in always run.

Comment: But what is the use of the condition and whose job is it to make condition 0xE. Are these just padding bits?

Comment: EVERY instruction has a condition ADDEQ add if equal, vs ADD, always.  SWILT SWI if less than, SWIEQ, SWI if equal.  SUBGT, sub if greater than, etc.  It is the programmers job to write the code, the programmer chooses when to make an instruction conditional or not.

Comment: Padding bits would be marked as SBZ usually (Should Be Zero), and not documented otherwise.  Conditional bits are very real and are often used, usually with branches blt, beq, etc, but with arm can be used on any instruction to inprove performance at times.

Comment: @dwelch Thanks a lot, now I understand. You wish to say that every instruction have a condition which can be mentioned explicitly (eg. ADDEQ, ADDGT etc.) and some are implicit (ADD - always). And over here also the case is same. Thank again. It really helped and I learned a new thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fundamental ARM concept.  Try to [google ARM conditional execution OR instructions](https://www.google.ca/#q=arm+conditional+execution+OR+instructions).  For instance, today the [Dave's space post](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/conditional.html) gives a good overview of this concept.  As well, [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Conditional_execution) referenced from the [Stackoverflow ARM wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arm/info) has information on this topic.

In brief, ARM has four condition bits or flags **NZCV**<sup>note</sup>; these are standard concepts to any assembler/machine language.  They are,

1. *N* for negative.
2. *Z* for zero.
3. *C* for carry.
4. *V* for overflow.

ARM has 16 conditional execution prefixes represented in a four bit field that test variations of the condition bits,

- 0000 - `EQ` meaning *Equal* with *Zero* flag set.
- 0001 - `NE` meaning *Not equal* with the *Zero* clear.
- 0010 - `CS` meaning *Carry set* or `HS` meaning *unsigned higher or same* with *Carry* set.
- 0011 - `CC` meaning *Carry clear* or `LO` meaning *unsigned lower* with *Carry* clear.
- 0100 - `MI` meaning  *Minus* or *negative* with the *Negative* flag set.
- 0101 - `PL` meaning *Plus* (including zero) with the *Negative* flag clear.
- 0110 - `VS` meaning *Overflow* with the *Overflow* flag set.
- 0111 - `VC` meaning *No overflow* with the *Overflow* clear.
- 1000 - `HI` meaning an *Unsigned higher* with *Carry* set **AND** *Zero* clear.
- 1001 - `LS` meaning  *Unsigned lower or same* with *Carry* clear **AND** *Zero* set.
- 1010 - `GE` meaning  *Signed greater than or equal* with *Negative* equal to *Overflow*.
- 1011 - `LT` meaning  *Signed less than* with *Negative* not equal to *Overflow*.
- 1100 - `GT` meaning  *Signed greater than* with *Zero* clear **AND** *Negative* equal to Overflow.
- 1101 - `LE` meaning  *Signed less than or equal* with *Zero* set **AND** *Negative* not equal to *Overflow*.
- 1110 - `AL` meaning  *Always*.  If there is no conditional part in assembler this encoding is used.
- 1111 - `NV`; this is historical and deprecated, but for ARMv3 it meant *never*.  Ie a `nop`.  For newer ARMs (ARMv5+), this extends the op-code range.

Almost all **ARM** instructions are prefixed with this four bit field.  This does not apply to **Thumb** or **Thumb2** instructions.  In unified assembler (assembles for either **Thumb2** or **ARM**), the [`IT` prefix](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjabicci.html) is used.

An example might be as follows.  You have this 'C' code,

```
 if(size > 0)
    write(fd, buffer, size);
```

The call `write()` is an OS call.  The following is some sample assembler,

```
 ; fd is in r0, buffer in r1, size in r2

 cmp  r2, #0         ; if(size > 0)
 movgt r7, #NR_write ; OS constant for write().
 swigt #0            ; call OS write() if(size > 0)

 ; code resumes here whether or not the OS was called.
```

There are many [other uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781523/double-conditions-in-arm-assembly) for the ARM conditionals.

**Note:** All modern ARM CPUs have a **Q** (saturation) flag.  It behaves in a different way as it is an extension to the instruction set.