# What does the MOVHS command in ARM assembly do?

Tags: assembly, arm, 32-bit, keil, jump-table

I'm having a hard time understanding what this command does. I'm guessing it means mov halfword signed into a register, but i'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Next time consult a [reference](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Chdehgih.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Condition bits in SWI (ARM Instruction)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804734/condition-bits-in-swi-arm-instruction)

Answer (score 3):

I would assume it's a normal move that only occurs if the current condition codes indicate "higher or same" (unsigned >= from previous compare or subtract).

Comment: Indeed. The canonical mnemonic is `CS` (carry set), but `HS` is a recognised synonym (as is `LO` for `CC`).

Answer (score 1):

This does not have anything to do with halfword or signed. The [ARM info center](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp) is always a good place to start if your confused, rather than guessing. Anyway, to answer your question, what this command or mnemonic does is it looks in the [CSPR (Current Program Status Register)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/CHDFAEID.html), and goes off of the value stored in there. Now this could be the result of an earlier call like `cmp r0, r1`. Say that this was the case, and `cmp r0, r1` was called before the code `movhs` was called. Now, the status of the `cmp` call is stored in the CPSR, and when a conditional such as `hs` or `cs` is added on as in the case with `movhs`, what this means is that this statement will only execute if the result in the CPSR is higher or same, i.e., in pseudocode, `if (r1 >= r0){execute the mov command}`.