# while loop with multiple conditions in ARM

Tags: c, arm

I am trying to understand how to do a while loop with multiple conditions in ARM assembly.

For example trying to code this:

```
                  while ((i>0)&&(val < (ls->sortedList[i-1])))
```

I understand how the logic of a while loop works in ARM assembly and I get how I would code both of those compares separately. I am just confused on how you would make it so the while loop doesn't continue unless both of those conditions are true in ARM assembly.

Thank you!

Comment: Try compiling the file which contain this command with `gcc -S` (if you use gcc)

Comment: Check this link possibly has the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781523/double-conditions-in-arm-assembly

Comment: Consider that `while (i>0) {...}` could be expressed as `while(1) { if (i>0) break; ... }`, and that you already know how to implement that, then consider how short-circuit logic operators are evaluated.