# Assembly code comparison fails for 0xFFE700DE >0xA

Tags: assembly, arm, comparison-operators

As a loop condition I am using the following code.

```
CMP     r5 , #0xA
BGE     Loop
```

But when the value in r5 is very large, say, FFE700DE, the comparison fails. Is it because it is signed value? How can I compare unsigned?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `BHS` instruction, which is unsigned "higher or same" comparison. See for instance [this list of ARM condition codes](https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/architectures-and-processors-blog/posts/condition-codes-1-condition-flags-and-codes).

Remember that for integer registers, the *value* in the register cannot *really* be signed or unsigned, it's all up to the *instruction* you use to interpret the value. The value is just a bunch of bits.

---

Other signed conditions include `bgt` / `blt`.
The unsigned equivalents are `bhi` (higher) and `blo` (lower).
See also a table [in a tutorial / guide](https://azeria-labs.com/arm-conditional-execution-and-branching-part-6/) of all 15 ARM conditions for predication as well as branches. (Including `AL` = always.  Also the historical 16th, `NV` = never, obsolete after ARMv4.)

Comment: but i need to compare if the value is greater than or equal to 0xA not just greater than

Comment: Did you have a look at the link above? HS = higher or same, unsigned

Comment: arm has an excess of conditionals, if you dont have all of those you can generally use negative logic, if not less than for example.  depending on the architecture you may only need to check one flag.

Comment: @Peter Cordes NV = Never is history, is last appeared in ARMv4.

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin: Thanks.  Is that tutorial in the 2nd link obsolete?  If we're going to link a tutorial in a canonical answer, hopefully the rest of the tutorial is good.  Or probably some official documentation would be a good idea.  I don't have time for a few hours; if you do or know some good links, you could edit.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That's the only error I can find.